# Nodejs versions confusion

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install the latest nodejs version using this installation steps for ubuntu via apt-get install  on https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Why that install version v0.4.9 instead of the lastest stable version v0.6.10 ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Package managers usually have a process for getting new versions of packages included in their repositories. Usually only security patches are expedited through that process, so until a new version of Ubuntu comes out, you may be waiting a while for newer versions of Node.js.

The solution is to use a trusted PPA (Personal Package Archive) like [this one](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/) by Chris Lea, he's got the latest stable version of Node.js published for you to install.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Tanks for help, but how can I get this v0.6.10 from that  Chris Lea PPA for ubuntu oneiric? Regards

Comment: You'll need to add the repository to your machine, via `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js`. After that, you can just run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: Another option would be to build nodejs from source.